# Group rows in HTML table

Tags: html, css

[image]

so is it basically a normal table with an extra header with columns and rows grouped at the end, it is possible to do something like this in HTML or maybe using css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use rowspan you can make it work

```
<td rowspan="3"></td>
```

Will make a cell in one column span 3 rows. Read up more here: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-table-rowspan-and-colspan-in-HTML#:~:text=The%20rowspan%20and%20colspan%20are,3%20will%20span%20three%20columns](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-table-rowspan-and-colspan-in-HTML#:%7E:text=The%20rowspan%20and%20colspan%20are,3%20will%20span%20three%20columns).

Comment: that was actually so easy to do, ty.